# Remove view controller from memory in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using a few view controllers for my app. I switch view controllers programmatically by using this code:

```
func jumpToVC() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        [unowned self] in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("whatVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This works but the VC stays in the memory, it won't completely removes itself out of the memory. Adding this line of code did not help me out:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

So how can I remove a view controller completely out of his memory?

Comment: Why are you using the GCD library, are you in a background thread?

Comment: When move for view controller to view controller using segues, etc you keep a hierarchy, so you're not removing any view controller from the memory

Comment: @VictorSigler GCD library? I do not know what that is. I got the function from another topic on here. It works, but the VC won't get out of the memory. Is there any way how I can remove the VC from the memory? Thank you